# Reload page after some time on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

I have a page that gets the contents from a servlet. The page gets updated with javascript every minute. When the mobile wakes up (I am using [jquery.wakeup-plugin](https://github.com/paulokopny/jquery.wakeup-plugin) ) and it was 'asleep' for more than 60 secs, I call :

```
location.reload(true);
```

or

```
window.location.href = window.location.href;
```

First line works for Chrome and Firefox but not for Safari, and the second line doesn't work for Safari and Chrome.
It reloads the page, but the page doesn't update. It shows the content before it went to sleep. After pressing F5 all browsers reload just fine.

Any tips on how to fix the refresh?

---

```
var bell_id = $.wakeUp(function(sleep_time) {

    if (sleep_time > 59000) {
        //location.reload(true); NOT WORKING FOR SAFARI
        window.location.href = window.location.href;
        $.ignoreBell(bell_id);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

U mean like that?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    cache_clear()
  }, 60000);
});

function cache_clear() {
  window.location.reload(true);
  // window.location.reload(); use this if you do not remove cache
}
```

Comment: I've updated my question to see my code for refreshing